# Problemas con las librerías de Facades de laravel 5.1 en heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku

Uso dos funcionalidades de Facades en mi proyecto de laravel 5.1 para enviar correos, y pongo las siguientes rutas en mi **AuthController**:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\hash;
```

Y todo funciona bien en mi local, el problema está en que cuando quiero probar mi proyecto en el hosting de heroku, entonces me encuentro con los siguientes errores:

> FatalThrowableError in AuthController.php line 116: Class
>   'Illuminate\Support\Facades\hash' not found

y

> FatalThrowableError in AuthController.php line 97: Class
>   'Illuminate\Support\Facades\mail' not found

lo cual es muy raro porque si funciona correctamente en mi local, por que en heroku me da esos errores? acaso se trata de alguna configuración especial que debo hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las palabras **hash** y **mail** tienen las primeras letras en minúsculas. *Heroku* corre sobre *Linux* y es *Case-Sensitive*.

Esta sería la forma correcta:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, solucioné agregandole \ a los métodos, por ejemplo \mail y \hash en los algoritmos donde los usaba, y el llamado a la librería quedó tal cual, y me corrió fino, de todas maneras probaré tu sugerencia a ver si corre así. En todo caso, te agradezco mucho tu respuesta.